# html-to-xlsx jsreport recipe with initial xlsx template file - HTTP API request

Tags: html, api, http, xlsx, jsreport

I try to generate xlsx-to-html recipe report with JsReport HTTP API https://jsreport.net/learn/api and initial attached xlsx template.

The documentatio is missing how to build request body to pass additional xlsx file like in bleow examples:

- html-to-xlsx recipe example: https://playground.jsreport.net/w/admin/QiHIBqsq
- xlsx recipe example: https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/Hy_V2BSh-4

I tried to add in template object following object:

```js
template: {
   ...
   engine: "handlebars",
   recipe: "html-to-xlsx",
   xlsxTemplate: {
      content: "base64_string_of_template_xlsx_file_........."
   }
   ...
}
```

but with no success.

How should be constructed JSON body for this request?

Comment: https://jsreport.net/learn/html-to-xlsx 
check Options "insertToXlsxTemplate " boolean field ... i was only able to do it by the studio not the api though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find proper json that is consumed properly by JsReport:

```
{
   "Template": {
      "Content": "template def string..",
      "Recipe": "html-to-xlsx"
      "Engine": "handlebars",
      "BaseXlsxTemplate": {
         "Content": "base-template-string-encoded-as-base64",
      },
      "HtmlToXlsx": {
         "InsertToXlsxTemplate": true, 
         "WaitForJS" = false,
         "HtmlEngine" = "chrome"
      }
   },
   "Data": "Json data...",
   "Options": {...}
}
```